# How to Accept POST XML to Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have a web service that will be sending a `POST` to my site in the form of `XML` i am trying to figure out how to actually receive that `XML` data.

This will not be a file it will be a POST request of data

I can set up a route for it to post to but how can i caputure the info and send it to nokogiri so i can parse it

post URL is

```
website.com/post_everywhere/create_account
```

Routes:

```
resources :post_everywhere do
  post :create_account
end
```

controller:

```
class PostEverywhereController < ApplicationController
  def create_account

    /**** How do i capture the info here ****/

  end
end
```

Sample Data:

```
<PELoadPostings>
    <PostingAccount>
        <UserName></UserName>
        <Password></Password><!-- for post free without account, UserName and Password are not set -->
        <ContactName></ContactName>
        <ContactPhone></ContactPhone>
        <ContactFax></ContactFax>
        <ContactEmail></ContactEmail>
        <CompanyName></CompanyName>
        <UserID></UserID><!-- for posting with account ContactName, ContactPhone, ContactFax, CompanyName, and UserID are not set -->
    </PostingAccount>
    <PostLoads><!-- for removes this would be a RemoveLoads tag -->
        <load><tracking-number>493266</tracking-number><origin><city>BUENA PARK</city><state>CA</state><postcode></postcode><county></county><country></country><latitude>NaN</latitude><longitude>NaN</longitude><date-start><year>2009</year><month>06</month><day>04</day><hour>12</hour><minute>00</minute></date-start><date-end><year></year><month></month><day></day><hour></hour><minute></minute></date-end></origin><destination><city>CORAL SPRINGS</city><state>FL</state><postcode></postcode><county></county><country></country><latitude>NaN</latitude><longitude>NaN</longitude><date-start><year>2009</year><month>06</month><day>04</day><hour>12</hour><minute>00</minute></date-start><date-end><year></year><month></month><day></day><hour></hour><minute></minute></date-end></destination><equipment><v></v></equipment><loadsize fullload="true"><length>53</length><width></width><height></height><weight>09</weight></loadsize><load-count>1</load-count><stops>0</stops><distance>2600</distance><rate>0.00</rate><comment>DRY VAN</comment></load>
        <load><tracking-number>433693</tracking-number><origin><city>HARBESON</city><state>DE</state><postcode></postcode><county></county><country></country><latitude>NaN</latitude><longitude>NaN</longitude><date-start><year>2009</year><month>06</month><day>03</day><hour></hour><minute></minute></date-start><date-end><year></year><month></month><day></day><hour></hour><minute></minute></date-end></origin><destination><city>DETROIT</city><state>MI</state><postcode></postcode><county></county><country></country><latitude>NaN</latitude><longitude>NaN</longitude><date-start><year>2009</year><month>06</month><day>05</day><hour></hour><minute></minute></date-start><date-end><year></year><month></month><day></day><hour></hour><minute></minute></date-end></destination><equipment><r></r></equipment><loadsize fullload="true"><length>48</length><width></width><height></height><weight>42</weight></loadsize><load-count>1</load-count><stops>0</stops><distance>1</distance><rate>0.00</rate><comment></comment></load>
    </PostLoads>
</PELoadPostings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most common way, all request params in rails are available via

```
params
```

hash in controller

So you can fetch your XML via

```
params[:some_params]
```

To get within which param name they will be sent, you should contact that third-party service, that will send them.

Or it is possible to see params in development/production.log of Rails app.

Comment: ok so Rails will automatically pull in and decode the XML data. and be available using the params

Comment: It does not decode data. All XML will be available as a string in some of params values. So you should get it, and parse with Nokogiri

Comment: So with the sample data that i show there. would i be correct that everything would be in params[:PELoadPostings]

Comment: I guess so, you just have to parse this param value